# Wants to delete everything after last "/" in php

Tags: php

I want to delete everything after last "/" including that in php

```
/abc/dashboard
```

the desired result

```
 /abc
```

Comment: So what did you try and didn't work?

Comment: I tried nothing yet... actually i am unable to find related ans.

Comment: does this string exist in a variable or something?

Comment: it exist in a variable

Answer (score 1):

I believe substr and strrpos is the best solution.
Strrpos finds the last `/` in the string and returns the position.
Substr returns the string from position 0 to what strrpos returned (after last `/`).

```
$str = "/abc/dashboard";

Echo substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, "/"));
```

https://3v4l.org/CiZge

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "/abc/def/ghi"; // the variable containing your string

$str = explode("/", $str); // separates the string into chunks between the "/"'s and puts the chunks in an array

$str = array_slice($str,0,-1); // removes the last chunk

$str = implode("/",$str); // concatenates the array using "/"'s between each chunk
```

Comment: Answers on SO should always include a description of what your code does.

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.